# React 16.3.x new lifecycle events not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I've correctly updated React to latest (16.3.1). Correct version inside package.json and even if I make a `console.log(React.version)`

But for a reason I do not understand, I cannot manage to make the two new lifecycle events work in my code, for example:

```
  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('getSnapshotBeforeUpdate')
    return true
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps () {
    console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps')
    return {}
  }
```

never output in the console, while `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` does.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you declare this?

Comment: Did you also update `react-dom` to 16.3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oblosys pointed out in its comment, I just forgot to update react-dom too..